# Render Custom UIView to Storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

There's a new feature in Storyboards that allow custom UIViews to be rendered within Storyboards. Does anyone remember how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Swift:

Look at "What's New in Interface Builder" and "What's New in Xcode 6", or look up `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` in the apple docs.

### Objective-C:

In "What's New in Interface Builder" https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/ they do the example in Swift, if you want to do it in Objective-C, you use the equivalents `IB_DESIGNABLE` and `IBInspectable`. Here's the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html

Comment: Just changed your answer to reflect Swift & Objective-C

Comment: It's "IBInspectable", not "IB_INSPECTABLE".  Ugly and inconsistent, and I hope they fix it before finalizing iOS 8.

Comment: current link is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html

Answer (score 1):

First - Add CocoaTouch framework target to your project.

Second - Create your custom view classes in the framework target, class .h file should be decorated with IB_DESIGNABLE (for class) and IBInspectable (for properties that can be changed in Interface Builder). e.g.

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface CustomView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable NSString *promptText;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat borderWidth;

@end
```

Third - Go to Interface Builder and add UIView to your storyboard, then change it's class to your custom view.

What I found out (hard way) is that it's better if you don't start with a lot of existing code in the custom view but build it gradually, simultaneously looking on Interface Builder window with your custom view selected and Custom Class tab opened in Utilities window - there is "Designables" green or red button that will tell if IB is unable to render live preview for custom view, your framework will be compiled automatically on every save in the framework classes.

Managing to get UIImages/UIImageViews rendering in IB live view need extra work - see https://devforums.apple.com/message/1002168 how to get image resources for IB live previews.